# In a large set of entries across multiple sections, how can I loop through each section type in the set?

Tags: entries, sections

I have a set of entries from multiple channels and I want to loop through each section type that is in the set.

Something like

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

{% for entrySection in entries.sections %}
    {{ entrySection.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

So basically if I have 100 results from across 8 sections, is there a way I can list out those 8 sections separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [group filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group)

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

{% for sectionName, sectionEntries in entries | group('section.name') %}
    <h2>{{ sectionName }}</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in sectionEntries %}
            <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```